# A static field will leak contexts

Tags: android, class, methods, static, non-static

This is my code for a splash activity:

```
public class Loading extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityHome.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_main);
    }
}
```

All work OK but next warning is show :

```
This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur (myapp.activities.ActivitySplash.Loading) less... (Ctrl+F1) 
A static field will leak contexts.
```

If I change class to static non-static methods will be used and errors will pop-up for:

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityHome.class);
startActivity(homeIntent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_main);
```

So if I will use private class will get warning, if will try to use a static class will get errors. What to do to have clear code?

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` as a non static inner class will receive a reference to its parent class, the `Activity`. Hence the warning in your code.

In order to correct this and still have access to your activity, pass your activity as [weak reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference) into the constructor of the `AsyncTask`.

Then you can call your intent code in `onPostExecute` and check if your activity is still present in memory.

In my opinion you should also consider moving away from `AsyncTask`. Check out [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) or the modern [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler).

Comment: Or for this case, i think `new Handler().postDelay()` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Do not hold a reference to context in Asyntasks. Use a callback to delegate starting the new activity to the context activity itself. This is a common bad practice that will lead to a memory leak because the AsyncTask can outlive the context. That will avoid declaring it static and you will have only thread safe code.